# Used coupon not displaying in admin order

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping, rules

I have generated shopping cart rule which is applied for free shipping. If other rules are applied then it's displaying in order details in admin but free shipping rules is not.

I need to know which rule is applied for free shipping in admin order details page.

https://www.screencast.com/t/QwkudKUAm3c4

[image]

Comment: I am pretty much sure that coupon code is displayed in admin in totals block. If you are having some customization in there, then you might not be able to see that, but in a default Magento, it is saved with order and is displayed in admin as well.

Comment: When other coupons used like 30% discount is displaying but when used free shipping coupon code is not displaying in totals block. Please see screenshot.